# Sharing data between two controllers in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Inside homeController file I have function

```
 $scope.MyFunction = function () {              
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/SomeUrl/ActionToDo',
                    data: { id: 1001 },
                }).success(function (response) {
                    if (response.Status == 1) {
                        //success  to do                                
                        }
                        $modal.open({
                            controller: 'modalController',
                            templateUrl: '/app/views/modalTemplate.html',
                            resolve: {
                                myData: function () {
                                    return response;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert(error);
                    }
                }).error(function () {
                    alert('Error!');
                });
            }
```

Where I'm calling modalController to open modal window. Question is how can I pass data to this controller (modalController) from homeController in order to inject currently selected language which is available inside homeController in variable `$scope.selLanguage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject it into controller as resolve dependency:

```
$modal.open({
    controller: 'modalController',
    templateUrl: '/app/views/modalTemplate.html',
    resolve: {
        myData: function () {
            return response;
        },
        language: $scope.selLanguage
    }
});
```

so it will be available in controller as service

```
.controller('modalController', function(myData, language) {
    console.log(language);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

passed the data as locals to the modal controller using resolve.

```
resolve: {
        myData: function () {
            return response;
        },
        modalVar: $scope.selLanguage
    }
```

In modalController refer that variable as it is local to that modalController controller.

```
angular.module('demo').controller('modalController', function ($scope, $modalInstance, modalVar) {

  $scope.modalVar= modalVar; 
});
```

Please refer [this](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)  for more